# replace value in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, addition

```
<Person>
<AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Profile">
<AdditionalAttribute name="First Name" value="John"/>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Last Name" value="Smith"/>
</AdditionalAttributes>

<AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Additional">
<AdditionalAttribute name="email" value="John Smith(jsmith)"/>
<AdditionalAttribute name="Created Date" value="2016-04-20T19:50:01Z"/>
</AdditionalAttributes>
</Person>
```

Can you show me how to use xslt to add @gmail.com to value of element email 
from John Smith (jsmith)   to   John Smith(jsmith**@gmail.com**)
assuming email value is dynamic

thanks and regards

Comment: It likely can be done during a copy of the full xml file except a special processing for the email value, but it would be much easier with a regexp search/replace with tools like sed/awk...

Comment: No, it wouldn't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0**

Similar to the solution of michael.hor257k , but **using [AVT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates)s** -- Attribute-Value Templates.

**Thus no need for an `<xsl:attribute>` operator**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AdditionalAttribute[@name='email']">
    <AdditionalAttribute name="email"
        value="{substring-before(@value, '(')
                }({substring-before(
                             substring-after(@value,'('),
                             ')'
                                    )}@gmail.com)">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='value')]"/>
    </AdditionalAttribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Person>
    <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Profile">
        <AdditionalAttribute name="First Name" value="John"/>
        <AdditionalAttribute name="Last Name" value="Smith"/>
    </AdditionalAttributes>
    <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Additional">
        <AdditionalAttribute name="email" value="John Smith(jsmith)"/>
        <AdditionalAttribute name="Created Date" value="2016-04-20T19:50:01Z"/>
    </AdditionalAttributes>
</Person>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Person>
   <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Profile">
      <AdditionalAttribute name="First Name" value="John"/>
      <AdditionalAttribute name="Last Name" value="Smith"/>
   </AdditionalAttributes>
   <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Additional">
      <AdditionalAttribute name="email" value="John Smith(jsmith@gmail.com)"/>
      <AdditionalAttribute name="Created Date" value="2016-04-20T19:50:01Z"/>
   </AdditionalAttributes>
</Person>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0**

This transformation uses AVT again and the XPath 2.0 **[`replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-replace)** function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AdditionalAttribute[@name='email']">
    <AdditionalAttribute name="email"
        value="{replace(@value, '\)', '@gmail.com)')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='value')]"/>
    </AdditionalAttribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i'm using xslt 1.0, and all your suggestion works.  I'm trying to do this  
<Items>
<Item itemIdentifier="07068283" code="Hello" />
<Item itemIdentifier="07059182" code="Hello" />
<Item itemIdentifier="07063805" code="Bye" />
<Item itemIdentifier="07064878" code="Bye" />
</Items>   I want to replace all value of attribute code="Hello" to code="Chao". this code below does it, but it also remove value of code="Bye"     <xsl:template match="Item/@code">
    <xsl:attribute name="code">
      <xsl:if test=". = 'Hello'">Chao</xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: @user12448901 Glad it works, Please, *accept* the answer and ask a new question with the new problem. Notify me via a comment when you have posted the new question.

Comment: thanks Dimitre for your help.  here is my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143630/xslt-replaces-attributes-value-correctly-but-also-empties-other-attributes

Comment: @user12448901,  There is already a good answer by michael.hor257k

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AdditionalAttribute[@name='email']/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ')')"/>
        <xsl:text>@gmail.com)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This is assuming there are no closing parentheses other than the last one. Alternatively, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="AdditionalAttribute[@name='email']/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, string-length(.) - 1)"/>
        <xsl:text>@gmail.com)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Added:

> Can you also show me how to replace "John Smith(jsmith)" with "jsmith@gmail.com" ?

Extract the text in parentheses and append the domain name to it:

```
<xsl:template match="AdditionalAttribute[@name='email']/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '('), ')')"/>
        <xsl:text>@gmail.com</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank you for quick reply.  i ran my java code against your xsl and it gave me this error  "SystemId Unknown; Line 7; Column 41; Illegal attribute name: email"  And the xml output for email is  <AdditionalAttribute name="email" />   There's no value

Comment: You can see it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNyf

Comment: many thanks to your guidance... i found the error  <xsl:attribute name="email">  , i changed to  <xsl:attribute name="value"> as you recommended and it works.   Can you also show me how to replace "John Smith(jsmith)" with "jsmith@gmail.com" ?

Comment: I don't see why using `email` as the name of the attribute should cause an error (unless you're validating the result against a schema). -- See the addition to my answer for your follow-up question.